# Marker interface or annotations?

Tags: java, interface, annotations

I need to mark some classes as Invokable - just to tell I can invoke methods of the class using reflection. But I don't like the idea of having an empty interface just for this purpose. Can this be done with annotations and still preserve behaviour on the example below? (I have never created my own annotations, so I'm not familiar with them in depth)

`Example`

```
class ClassOne implements Invokable {
}

class ClassTwo implements Invokable {
}

void someMethod(Invokable inv) {
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of `someMethod`, you can't use annotations. Perhaps later you'll find that `Invokable` may need useful methods anyway.

Also, be sure to check out already existing interfaces like `Callable`, `Future` etc. before you re-invent the wheel.

Comment: If I understand it, annotations are just like some properties which don't affect design at all, do they? I use the interface then. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, but the point in your case is you can't easily use them as types. For example, if you mark some class as `@Foo` this does **not** mean that the class *implements* the `Foo` interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the annotations of a class mit Class.getAnnotations() and search for your Invokable annotation. Then you can get the method you want to invoke, and invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

the decision would depend on how you are going to use these classes. if you have many classes some Invokable and some not, you may be better off with annotations, just pass the objects/ classes and check for the annotation. if you know the classes you would be passing would all be Invokable, you could go with a marker interface.

i.e. assuming you only want to preserve the behaviour and not the method :-)