# Can annotations totally replace Marker Interfaces?

Tags: java, annotations, marker-interfaces

As marker interfaces are mostly useful for just marking a class, the same thing can be achievable through annotations. For example `Cloneable` interface can be `@Cloneable`.

So is there still need for marker interfaces or can be relpaced by Annotations? Is there any advantage/disadvantage of using any of them? I mean prefer one over other?

Comment: Marker interface was established as an antipattern even before Generics.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik previously marker interfaces were needed for metadata, but the same can now be achieved using annotations. That is why it is called an anti-pattern, am I right?

Comment: Yes, plus even on Java 1.4 there were recommendations to design without marker interfaces. Marker interfaces are an abuse of the concept of polymorphism.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marker interface or annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341354/marker-interface-or-annotations)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marker interfaces are better than annotations when they're used to define a type. For example, Serializable can be used (and should be used) as the type of an argument that must be serializable. An annotation doesn't allow doing that:

```
public void writeToFile(Serializable object);
```

If the marker interface doesn't define a type, but only meta-data, then an annotation is better.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing to mention would be the cost of using annotations. To check if object is an instance of an interface one can use `instanceof` which is a relatively low-cost operation nowadays. Using annotations requires `Java reflection` calls and is far more costly.